# Why would this insect pest poster in Taiwan have phonetic characters (Zhuyin) on every Chinese character?

Tags: writing, zhuyin-fuhao

In my Biology SE question [Identify this large, beige or pine cone-colored squareish beetle and/or the pine cone it's on?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/93014/27918) I included a snapshot of a poster I saw when hiking. I was told that it advises that the beetle shown in the photo is a pest. I can at least recognize that it begins with what looks like "小心!" There's no date on the poster but I assume that it's modern and not a historical reproduction.

I saw this poster while hiking in Taiwan.

I noticed that there are (almost always) a pair of phonetic characters (注音?) next to each Chinese characters. In Taiwan I see books of sutras and other prayers written this way, but I've never seen a public announcement that looked like this.

Is there any particular reason why this particular public notice would require the phonetic characters? Are they there as a courtesy? Is this considered artistic or stylized in any way? Does this make it more accessible (easier to read) or look more "official"?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Texts written for schoolchildren will be annotated with phonetic symbols. The last sentence indicates that this poster is made for schoolchildren:

> 如果發現了，趁著沒孵化之前通知老師來移除。
>
> *If any [eggs] are found, take the opportunity to let the teacher know, so that they can remove [the eggs] before they hatch.*

Comment: Ah, yes that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: I've cited a website written in Chinese in [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/94951/27918) to a different species identification question in Biology SE. If you have a moment to take a look, please feel free to edit if I've misquoted the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is [bopomofo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo). Taiwanese people use it instead of pinyin for transcription. They also use a bopomofo keyboard for typing on their phones.

I'm travelling in Taiwan right now and I've seen it in children's books:

[image: Children's book with bopomofo]

and in very few other places, such as the zoo:

[image: Zoo sign with bopomofo]

[image: Another zoo sign with bopomofo]